# making animated videos with pictures for birthdays or special days

Tags: sound, video, music

I am trying to find a program which is making animated videos with pictures for birthdays or special days.Most of the programs I found in internet was for windows or online which is asking money for their service.

Is there a good tool which will help me to make videos from the pictures I took ?

I have seen a command avconv for making video from the pictures but seems I can not edit video like adding some different animation and subtitles while creating that video ; also I hope to add some music or sound to those videos.

Comment: Try `openshot`. Maybe that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @Ziazis This should be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [openshot](http://www.openshot.org/ppa/)

It does all the things you listed and is free.